# Letter of nomination versus letter of recommendation for Sloan Fellowship

Tags: united-states, recommendation-letter

**Background:** I'm a math department administrator in the U.S. preparing to nominate one of our faculty for a Sloan Fellowship. As described [here](https://sloan.org/fellowships#tab-materials-required), fellowship candidates need to have:

> - A letter from a department head or other senior researcher officially nominating the candidate and describing his or her qualifications, initiative, and research;
>
> [...]
>
> - Three letters from other researchers (preferably not all from the same institution) written in support of the candidate’s nomination.

**My question:** how is a letter of nomination different in its requirements from the "three letters from other researchers"?

In particular, the three letters would be coming from researchers in the area of the candidate who can speak with authority about his research achievements, but I (and I expect the same is true for other department heads writing similar letters) am not an expert in the candidate's area so can only survey his achievements in a relatively superficial way. What is expected, and what is the best way to add value in such a letter of nomination on top of the three "standard" letters of recommendation?

**Scope:** please answer only if you have direct experience with the Sloan Fellowships or other similar type of fellowships, preferably in math or at least in STEM. I am not interested in "common sense" speculation based on parsing the required materials text I quoted above, which is something I can do well enough on my own.

Comment: Asking only people with experience with those fellowships to respond makes the question program-specific and thus off-topic.

Comment: @aeismail I don't think this question should be closed. Sloan is an important part of early-career funding in mathematics, and perhaps in other fields too. It's quite likely that a significant number of ASE posters have this experience.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning IMHO, the answer is "contact the organization behind the fellowship and ask". Way too specific to be posted here, regardless of how useful the information would be.

Comment: @FábioDias I understand your concern. It's true I am interested specifically in the Sloan, but between my specific situation and the most general question of "what to write in a letter of nomination for a fellowship/award when you are not an expert in the field of the person you are nominating?" I think there is a continuous spectrum of levels of generality (where one specializes to STEM, fellowships in the US etc), many parts of which are clearly on-topic. Note that I did say "Sloan ... or other similar types of fellowship", so I'm not limiting the scope to only this specific program.

Comment: If your university is large enough, talk to the...research office (not sure of the name). They're likely to have knowledge or experience in this area.